# Covariance of a Stationary Process

Tags: covariance, stationarity, white-noise

Let $Y_t$ be a stationary process such that $Y_1 = a_1$ and $Y_2 = \theta a_1 + a_2$, where $\theta$ is a parameter and $a_t$ is the white noise process with mean 2 and variance $\sigma^2_a = 0.5$. Find cov$(Y_1, Y_2)$.

According to the textbook the answer is $\theta\sigma_a^2$. However, I've tried using the definition
$${\rm cov}(Y_1, Y_2) = E[Y_1Y_2] - \mu_{Y_1}\mu_{Y_2}$$

however I keep getting a value of 0.

I think there is a property of covariance I must be missing here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show how you determined the covariance is zero?  Obviously the problem occurs somewhere in those steps.

Comment: Try using the following properties: $Cov(aZ + Y, X) = Cov(aZ,X) + Cov(Y,X)$ and $Cov(X,X) = Var(X)$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
{\rm Cov}(Y_1, Y_2) & = & {\rm Cov}(a_1, \theta a_1 + a_2) \\
& = & {\rm Cov}(a_1, \theta a_1) + {\rm Cov}(a_1, a_2) \\
& = & \theta{\rm Cov}(a_1, a_1) + 0 \\
& = & \theta {\rm Var}(a_1) \\
& = & \theta \sigma_a^2.
\end{eqnarray*}